# Neo4j Procedure and Transactions

Tags: java, plugins, neo4j

I am writing a procedure in Java for a Neo4j plugin.  The plug in is complex and I would like to separate the plugin into a series of classes.  Class 1 is the procedure itself.  Class 2 contains some helper methods, and works.  Class 3, however, is a different type of helper methods but they require me to invoke the GraphDatabaseService.Transaction class to create nodes. From debugging, it appears that this line is the problematic line:

```
Node newNode = tx.createNode(Label.label("Mylabel"));
```

After running a couple of experiments, it appears that perhaps one cannot execute a Transaction outside of the class that is decorated as a @Procedure.  Is that true?  I have not seen that in the documentation.  Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out and will share for those it may help.  In Class 3, you need to both import the Log and Transaction interfaces and use the decorators (which I knew already):

```
import import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.procedure.Context;
import org.neo4j.logging.Log;

public class Class 3 {
     @Context
    Public Transaction tx;
    @Context
    Public Log log;

    // Put your Methods Here
    

    // Put your constructor Here
    // Constructor
    public Class3v(Log log, Transaction tx) {
        this.log = log;
        this.tx = tx;
    }
}
```

Then, in the main class where you wrote your procedure, you need to "pass" the log and tx instances you created in that procedure to the above helper class 3 like so:

```
// Class1
import import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.procedure.Context;
import org.neo4j.logging.Log;

public class Class1 { 
     

    public     @Context
    public Log logClass1;
    @Context
    public Transaction txClass1;

    @Procedure(value = "WHATEVER", mode = Mode.WRITE)
    @Description("WHATEVER")
    public Stream<ReturnRecord> nameOfClass1 () {

        //  Other Stuff
        // Create Instance of Class 3 Object
        Class3 instanceOfClass3Object = new Class3 (logClass1, txClass1);
     
       
        return Stream.Of(new ReturnRecord());    
    }
    
    public class ReturnRecord () {
        // WHATEVER YOU HAPPEN TO HAVE HERE
    }
}
```